# How to crop a UIImageView to a custom shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

Is it possible for a user to draw a dotted line (in a circle) around the bit of the `UIImageView` they wish to crop to, and then for the `UIImageView` to resize to those points? It's a bit like the lasso/marquee effect in Photoshop:

[image]

Comment: Ah, so how would I be able to do this? How can I make the bits outside the marquee transparent? Well first of all I guess my question is - how can I get a CGRect of the inside section of the marquee from the drawing? I've currently got a UIKit drawing view set up with CGContext etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Since iOS 8.x, UIImageView provides a `maskView` property.  Just prepare an image with some opaque pixels, create another image view with that mask image, and set this mask image view as the maskView.  The opaque pixels in the mask image will be the ones shown in the underlying image.

```
    UIImageView *maskView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"somemask"]];
    maskView.frame = imageView.bounds;
    imageView.maskView = maskView;
    // imageView will be masked by maskView
```

.

**Original Answer**

There's quite a bit to do, but here's a high-level outline:

1. create an empty image which will become a mask
2. build a path in that image from user input
3. fill the path to turn it into a mask
4. apply the mask to the imageview's image

Create image: A simple idea here is to just ship a black image with your project.  It should be sized to match the maximum region a user can select.  Read the image into memory (`UIImage imageNamed:`) and set it up as the drawing context by calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.

Create path:  ([see apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html)).  When the user starts stroking the region, call `CGContextBeginPath`, then follow user gestures, sampling the touches and adding small segments by calling `CGContextMoveToPoint` repeatedly as touchesMoved.

Create mask: To turn the path into a mask you want a black background and the path filled with white.  If you started with a black image, you just need to do the fill.  See the same apple guide about doing that.

Finally, you'll apply this mask to your imageView's image.  [Here's a decent reference](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html) for that.

Comment: hi sir please help me my project face shape image crop try to many library but not perfect image crop let me know any idea ..

Comment: @RamaniHitesh - answer was a little out of date.  See if the improved technique helps you.

Comment: It ok sir don't worry ... any idea please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

This answers just one part of your question i suppose, but here's an [example](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/10/20/marching-ants-with-core-animation/) on how to draw and animate the dotted line (i.e. marching ants effect).