# Cropping ImageView in the Shape of Another ImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, crop, shapes

How can I crop my imageView into a bubble shape which I have the image in my project.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13016064/1407017) can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is simple code for **resizing or crop** image, you need to just pass **height or width** for image as you want:

**For Get Croped Image:**

```
UIImage *croppedImg = nil;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(AS YOu Need);
croppedImg = [self croppIngimageByImageName:self.imageView.image toRect:cropRect];
```

Use following method that return `UIImage` (*as You want size of image*)

```
- (UIImage *)croppIngimageByImageName:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        //CGRect CropRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height+15);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        return cropped;
    }
```

Here you get Croped Image that return by above method;

**OR RESIZING**

And also Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** with **image** for **Resizing UIImage**:

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you want.

Comment: Hi. iPatel My name Ramani one help , My project one concept is image crop face shape but not perfect face shape crop let me know any idea please declare ,,,,

Comment: @RamaniHitesh sure let me know what you did or provide your source code.

Comment: Uimageview *cropView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 200, 60, 60)];
    cropView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cropView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cropView.layer.cornerRadius=cropView.bounds.size.width/2.0f;
    cropView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
    [cropView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];     CGRect rect = self.cropView.frame;
    CGRect drawRect = [self cropRectForFrame:rect];
    UIImage *croppedImage = [self imageByCropping:self.image toRect:drawRect];
    return croppedImage;

Comment: @RamaniHitesh I think it will help you https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mdimagecroper and for more custom crop library you can find out from https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?page=1&q=crop

Comment: sir in this library use but this library only one shape my project more than face shape  also move around image move and scale .."mdimagecropper" free hand lib not my side work..

Comment: Bhai thodu costomise karvu pade .. bethe-bethu to na male ne dost :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155824/discussion-between-ramani-hitesh-and-ipatel).